# How to concatenate all lists within a list in jinja?

Tags: jinja2

I am trying to do:

```
lofl = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
sum(lofl, []) # [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

in jinja2. I tried:

```
sum(lofl,[])
lofl|sum([])
```

but both didn't work. How can I concatenate all lists within a list in jinja?

Comment: It does. It's not very elegant, but if that's the only way.

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to add a custom `flatten` filter to your Jinja environment (using e.g. the code you present in the first part of your question).

Comment: Or heavily inspire from the Ansible `flatten` filter.